# Finding the time between datetime values in metric format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to have a 'Duration' field in the format *hours.minutes* but I would like the minutes to be 'metric' (by which I mean in decimal format).
For example, the difference between 
`'2016-11-02 12:00:00.000'`and`'2016-11-02 13:45:00.000'` would be `1.75`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2016-11-02 12:00:00.000', '2016-11-02 13:45:00.000')/60.0 AS DECIMAL(5,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2016-11-02 12:00:00.000', '2016-11-02 13:45:00.000')/86400.0 AS DECIMAL(5,2))
```

Comment: SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2016-11-02 12:00:00.000', '2016-11-02 13:45:00.000')/60.0 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) this one would give the asker's expected result

Comment: @encryptoferia Perfect!

Comment: @encryptoferia Thanks!